# serve static file and fallback to dynamic content if static file not there

Tags: nginx, dynamic, url-rewriting, static

when someone visit
/mypage-234.html

I want nginx to:

- first look for a static file "234" in a directory
- if that static file is not available, it will serve the content dynamically

To get the static file I can do a rewrite

```
rewrite ^/mypage-([a-zA-Z0-9]*).*$  /staticfiles/$1 break;
```

but then it will not fallback to the dynamic content if the file is not there

so I thought using try_files, something like this would work, but it doesnt:

```
location ~ "/mypage-([a-zA-Z0-9]*).*" {
   try_files /staticfiles/$1 /php/dynamic.php?id=$1;
}
```

(php is already setup and working, so it is the matter of getting it to fallback when the static file is not there that is the issue)

Comment: Your `try_files` solution is the correct approach. What doesn't work? Does it go to PHP each time? What value have you set to `root` and what is the full pathname of the static file?

Comment: I found the problem, I have a rewrite that I want to catch "all" if nothing else matters `rewrite ^/(.*).html?$ /php/dosomething.php?f=$1 last;`, but how nginx handles priority that will match first. So no solution yet how i get these two to work together